# Is there any sample application for ACAccount in IOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to access some user account details from iphone. I think in ios 5 I can grab these details using Accounts framework. Is there any sample application showing how to access these details using Accounts framework? Otherwise just guide me how to do it.

Comment: If you want sample applications of iOS stuff, why don't you just look at the Apple documentation and example code?

Comment: I checked in Apple documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019 ) for sample code. But I didn't find any sample application linked to that document.

Comment: Try the search function for ACAccount : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Listings/Tweeting_TweetingViewController_m.html

Comment: Actually I tried that too. But unfortunately I searched for ACAccount in documents section, so I couldn't find the sample code. Anyway thanks for the help :). Its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ACAccounts` framework currently only supports Twitter the sample code for it is contained within this project, showing the new Twitter frameworks:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011191

It uses `ACAccount` to fetch a user's Twitter account(s) and initiate a post. It's quite a straightforward class, so hopefully this will prove valuable to you.